# Can C++ code be called from a Java applet?

Tags: java, c++, browser, applet, java-native-interface

I'm curious if I can do this.  Can C++ code compiled and loaded on the local host be called from a Java applet running in a browser?

Comment: What do you mean by "C++ be called"?  Do you mean a C++ compiler or some specific software written in C++?

Comment: You really should edit this for clarity, or it will likely be closed very soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be done **if** your applet is signed **and** the user agrees to grant the Applet full privileges.